# Drop down menu cut-off after SlideOut

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I'm using a drop-down-menu which I modified to use animations such as SlideOut and FadeIn using onmouseover and onmouseout.
The problem comes after hovering through all of the nested lists a few times, which results in the second nested list becoming cut off.

You can replicate the bug by moving from "nav 1" to "nav 2" and back again rapidly.

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WfkCY/2/embedded/result,js,html,css/)

Screenshot of cut-off:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53879403/screenshot.png

Please and thank you for any advice / criticism.

Comment: are you referring to sub menu of Nav 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SuRJ9/

The code I've changed:

```
function slideDown(toSlide) {
    currentHover(toSlide);
    $($(toSlide).children('ul')[0]).slideDown('medium',
        function(){   $(this).css('overflow','visible') });
}
```

I've added resetting `overflow` to `visible` after finishing animation. `overflow` is set to `hidden` by jQuery in order to make sliding animation.

Also, please don't use `onmouseout="slideUp(this)"` and `onmouseover="slideDown(this)"`, this is obtrusive JavaScript and is a bad technique. You should assign these events using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

`$.fadeOut/In()` apply certain styles before running the animation. These are remove when the animation completes.

Your `fadeOutNav()` is calling stop(true) , which if done while fadeOut() or fadeIn() are working, will leave the style's they have applied to the element. In this case overflow:hidden on the parent ul. You can remove the stop and let the effects bubble up, or insert a `.css('overflow','')` to your chain.