# Prevent Javascript function from firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7Qpj/)

I use a customized drop-down menu which runs on jQuery events and animations.

The problem occurs when I activate the drop-down via `mouseenter` several times, which results in the menu sliding down then sliding up several times. I tried to fix it by adding `.stop(true)`, which was successful, but it resulted in other problems like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020534/drop-down-menu-cut-off-after-slideout/12020685#12020685)
I followed that advice([jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fuABW/)), but it causes more unattractive problems.

I need is a way to stop a function from firing redundantly, but still be able to stop a "slide down" immediately and then "slide up" if the user triggers `.mouseleave`.

I tangled with custom queues for a good 5 hours, with no success :(

Any ideas, advice, and criticism is welcome.

Comment: Maybe if you check for the proper condition to stop the code and return false?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for [debouncing](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/).

Answer (score 1):

Basically it boils down to delaying the execution of the event handler.

```
var mouseoverTimer = null;    

$('.elem').mouseover(function(){

   clearTimeout(mouseoverTimer); //ignore previous trigger

   mouseoverTimer  = setTimeout(function(){ //wait to execute handler again
     //execute actual handler here
   }, 10);
});
```

If the same handler was called within the specified interval the pending execution is cancelled and queued again to execute 10ms later hoping that there's no subsequent trigger within that interval.