# HTML appending multiple times when window resizes

Tags: jquery, append, media-queries, multiple-instances, window-resize

I am wanting to append some HTML content from a variable for smaller screen sizes.However when I resize the browser the content appends(as it should) but if I keep moving the window it continues to append multiple copies of the HTML.

How could I prevent it from doing this?

This what I am doing:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
      width = parseInt(width);
        if (width < 700) {
            $('ul.nav li.top ul.submenu').removeAttr("style");
            $('body').append(str);  // this is when I am having the problem appending

        } else if (width >= 700) {
            $('ul.nav').removeAttr("style");
            $('.form-wrapper').removeAttr("style");
            var toggle = function(direction, display) {
            return function() {
              var self = this;
              var ul = $('ul.submenu', this);
              if( ul.css('display') === display && !self['block' + direction] ) {
                self['block' + direction] = true;
                ul['slide' + direction]('fast', function() {
                  self['block' + direction] = false;
                });
              }
            };
          };
          $('ul.nav li.top').hover(toggle('Down', 'none'), toggle('Up', 'block'));
          $('ul.nav li.top ul.submenu').hide();
          $('#gallery').remove();
        } else {

        }
    }
$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: why not use media queries for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [debounce](http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/) the resize event such that it fires **only when resize is complete**.

This is required because -

> - In IE, Safari, and Chrome many resize events fire as long as the user    continues resizing the window.
> - Opera uses as many resize events, but    fires them all at the end of the resizing.
> - Although, Firefox fires one resize event at the end of the resizing.

Following is a snippet from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119107/prevent-javascript-function-from-firing-multiple-times/12119274#12119274).

```
var resizeTimer = null;    

$(window).resize(function(){

   clearTimeout(resizeTimer); //ignore previous trigger

   resizeTimer= setTimeout(function(){ //wait to execute handler again
     //execute actual handler here
   }, 10);
});
```

---

In addition to this, I suggest you have a placeholder for adding your content -

```
$('body #appendTarget').html(str); //Since .append() will anyways append multiple times
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your adjustStyle function you could remove the event handler with `$(window).off('resize')` or just have a boolean that defaults to true but is set to false on the first run through.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is appending the values to the page, or just adding them to what's there.  What it sounds like what you want to do is just replace the value.  Use the .html() function instead of .append().